# Should K&R indentation work in C++ code?

Tags: indentation, c++

Given the following file, named as `x.cpp` I get the following unexpected indentation behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class X {
public:
     X()
          {  // <-- Why the indent?
               printf("Hello!");
          }
};
int main() { X x; }

// Local Variables:
// c-file-style: "k&r"
// End:
```

I know that this file is not valid C source, but if I rename the file to `x.c` and re-indent, I suddenly get the expected indentation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class X {
public:
     X()
     {  // <-- Looks good
          printf("Hello!");
     }
};
int main() { X x; }

// Local Variables:
// c-file-style: "k&r"
// End:
```

Obviously, the problem is a difference in the way the file is parsed syntactically in the two different major modes.  In C mode, the brace on line 5 is seen as `substatement-open`, while in C++ mode it is seen as `inline-open`.  Since the emacs definition of "k&r" style doesn't specify an indent for `inline-open` it defaults to something silly.

My question then, is whether it is reasonable to expect that "k&r" indentation style should work in C++.  In other words, should I file an emacs bug for this?  Or am I missing something that would make this work as expected?

Comment: I discovered that "bsd" style is a good substitute for "k&r" that seems to play nicer with C++.